# Java 8: How to copy files written in a list to a TXT file from one directory to another directory?

Tags: java, java-8, nio, java-io

I have a simple text file called `small_reports.txt` that looks like:

```
report_2021_05_02.csv
report_2021_05_05.csv
report_2021_06_08.csv
report_2021_06_25.csv
report_2021_07_02.csv
```

This reported is generated with my java code and takes in each of these files from the directory `/work/dir1/reports` and writes them into the file `combined_reports.txt` and then places the txt file back into `/work/dir1/reports`.

My question is, for each line in `small_reports.txt`, find that same file (line) in `/work/dir1/reports` and then COPY them to a new directory called `/work/dir1/smallreports`?

Using Java 8 & NIO (which is really helpful and good) I have tried:

```
Path source = Paths.get("/work/dir1/reports/combined_reports.txt");
Path target = Paths.get("/work/dir1/smallreports/", "combined_reports.txt");
        
if (Files.notExists(target) && target != null) {
    Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(target.toString()));
}
Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

But this is just copying the actual txt file `combined_reports.txt` into the new directory and not the contents inside like i  thought it would.

Comment: `Path target = Paths.get("/work/dir1/smallreports/", csvFileName);` is what you need. `List<String> csvFileNames = Files.readAllLines(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("small_reports.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));`

Comment: @g00se 

Can you reply with an answer instead of a comment, it's hard for me to read the lines like that sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final String SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp";
final String TARGET_DIR = "/tmp/root/delme";
List<String> csvFileNames = Files.readAllLines(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("small_reports.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

for (String csvFileName : csvFileNames) {
    Path source = Paths.get(SOURCE_DIR, csvFileName);
    Path target = Paths.get(TARGET_DIR, csvFileName);
    if (Files.notExists(target) && target != null) {
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(target.toString()));
    }
    Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Should do it for you. Obviously change the constants appropriately

Comment: Thank you very much, and is there a way to add error handling in the sense that the file is somehow not found in the directory from the text file? Maybe if it were to be accidentally deleted?

I tried testing it by making a wrong Path but it didn't catch an error or anything

Comment: Why not do the same testing as you're doing with the target?

Comment: sorry what did you mean by that?

Comment: *`if (Files.notExists(target) && target != null) {`* You did write this original code didn't you?

Comment: Yes i did write that, but isn't that just testing if the path exists, and if it doesn't exist then to create it? I don't want to create the path of looking for the file, only to place it in the new directory but if the file itself doesn't exist then to throw an error

Comment: So what's wrong with doing `if (Files.notExists(source))`?

Comment: Hmmm.. yeah I have no idea why I didn't think of that, literally had a huge brain fart thank you lol... if i wanted to throw an exception would throwing a RunTimeException be a proper one?

Comment: *literally had a huge brain fart* Seek medical help immediately! ;)

Comment: There’s no reason to use a construct like `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("small_reports.txt")`. Just `Paths.get("small_reports.txt")` is enough. Instead of `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` you can use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` which can not fail. Or just omit it, as [that’s the default](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)) anyway. While it’s already in the question, there’s no sense in `Paths.get(target.toString())` instead of just using `target`. Nor checking `target != null` *after* `Files.notExists(target)`.

Comment: Well, `target` can never be `null` anyway. Further, there’s no sense in calling `createDirectories` with the same path that is supposed to be the target of the copied CSV file. That way, `copy` will always fail as there’s a directory in the way. @stackerstack when you want to throw an exception in the erroneous case, just don’t make a check at all. `Files.copy(…)` *does* already throw an appropriate exception in that case.

Comment: @Holger could you reply with an answer so i can have a better scope of what you are trying to say? really appreciate it though

Comment: @stackerstack this code can be simplified to `Path source = Paths.get("/work/dir1/reports"), target = Paths.get("/work/dir1/smallreports");  for(String csvFileName: Files.readAllLines(source.resolve("small_reports.txt"))) { 
 Files.copy(source.resolve(csvFileName), target.resolve(csvFileName), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);  }`

Comment: @Holger ah i meant if you could reply as an actual answer to my question, i have a hard time reading comments because of eye alignment issues

Comment: @stackerstack answers and comments have different purposes, not just different appearances. When you have difficulties reading them, consider changing your browser’s zoom factor or copy the text into an editor where you can reformat it freely. Especially the code snippets work better when being copied into an IDE.